# MS Teams doesn't send any http request to bot application on install

Tags: java, botframework, microsoft-teams

I developed bot application using java sdk and emulator for testing. It works properly.

Than I created bot integration via Azure Bot Service and deployed app to some server. All app id and api endpoints where updated correspondingly.

The server successfully receives http request when I test via Web Chat, but MS Teams doesn't send any request to bot application while installing over custom package.

MS Teams doesn't provide any error on installation, I just saw few errors "Invalid user identity in provided tenant" on Bot Service page.

Another person created tenant account, but I'm marked as Global Administrator.

Any advices how to make MS Teams install is properly?

Comment: Can you provide the specifics of your set up? How have you connected your bot to the MS Teams application (via a bot registration channel)?

Comment: Additionally does your bot respond properly from your server to anywhere else?

Comment: I developed bot via botframework (java sdk) tested it via bot Bot Framework Emulator.
Than created Bot configuration via Bot Service and updated endpoint correspondingly to server api path.
Bot service receive http request and works with Web Chat in Bot Service tab.

But while I'm uploading to MS Teams via custom package it doesn't send anything.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "custom package"?

Comment: I meant "Upload a custom app" -> "Upload for me or my team"

Comment: Can you double check that you can get other (possibly non custom) bots on there as well?

Comment: I successfully installed random bot from store. Actually my user marked as Global Admin in Azure (by the way another person created this account).

Comment: @MarkB do you have access to Bot Service log? If yes than I may tell you bot id (4ca80baa-19ee-4814-bc4c-a6c7ca62baea) to check what's going on there.

Really I would recommend to MS Teams integration be more verbose.

Comment: I'm looking into that now, but did you add your bot to your account via [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/publishing/apps-publish)? If so try the following instead: go to the "channels" blade and click directly on "MSTeams" under "name" in the connect to channels table, that should pop up a window that opens a connection to your bot.

Comment: Yeah it opens connection to bot in MS Teams (there is possibility to open on Web page or desktop application). But when I text something to bot there is no any http request hitting bot backend server. And it's main point: Why MS Teams platform does't send any requests to configured endpoints (endpoint is live)?

Comment: Can you try out this bot on another channel (non-webchat, skype is easiest setup wise) and possibly try out a different channels registration with teams to see if you can get a different bot set up in there? (to check if it's something wrong with the tenant rather than the bot)

Comment: @MarkB, thanks for looking at.
I suppose that something wrong with tenant because similar configuration with the same bot worked on different account.
The mail point is: There is no any logs or useful information that may explain what is wrong. From time to time I see the following message: "Invalid user identity in provided tenant" but I cannot find explanation what does it mean and hot to fix it.

Comment: I'd recommend opening an issue for that, unfortunately there isn't anything specific to this within the github repos for botbuilder, so try opening one on [botbuilder-services](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/new) and it'll either get looked at there or you'll be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @RomanKoval- Did you try this bot in a Freemium/ Guest user account? Is it failing for normal tenant users as well?